# Robocopy reporting failed files but not showing in logs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, robocopy, windows-server-2019, fileserver

I am running a robocopy script to sync data from an old file server to a new one. Im running into an issue where the log is stating that there's 600+ failed files but the logs don't indicate any failed files.

For reference, here is the commands I'm running:
robocopy \fileserver\c$\FolderRedirection C:\FolderRedirection /XD $recycle.bin /R:0 /W:0 /S /E /Tee /Log:C:\robo\FolderRedirection.log /V /MIR /secfix /Copy:DATS /efsraw
robocopy \fileserver\c$\Shares C:\Shares /sec /R:0 /W:0 /S /E /Tee /Log:C:\robo\data.log /V /MIR /secfix /Copy:DATS /efsraw
pause

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found the following workaround/behavior.

At first I ran my robocopy command without /efsraw and had only a problem with one file being efs-crypted - but no other failed files.

So I added the /efsraw and now found hundreds and thousands of failed files stated in the robocopy-summary, but found no corresponding log-lines.

**After removing /efsraw robocopy ran without any failed files stated in the summary.**

So it seems to me, that /efsraw is a bit problematic...